# manually compiling ruby 1.8.7 on ubuntu hardy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, ubuntu-8.04

running two rails 2.3.8 apps on two virtual servers in ubuntu 8.04 with apache and passenger. the ruby version is 1.8.6

we are upgrading one of the apps to rails 3.0.4. my understanding is that we need ruby 1.8.7 to run the app. with this version of ubuntu we will need to compile ruby 1.8.7 manually.

1. never compiled manually before. if you know of any resources i should check out that would be great.
2. i have not been able to determine the version of passenger and am trying to make sure it will be compatible with rails 3.0.4. any suggestions?
3. the application we are leaving in 2.3.8 is our core business application and i need to make sure i don't mess it up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). Almost everybody use it now.

Early Passenger versions for Apache had some bugs so my suggestion is to simply upgrade Passenger to the newest version.

Comment: I am using rvm in my mac development environment. i'll see what i can find on using rvm in production.

Comment: Since its a server you might want to look into the [system-wide install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/) of RVM, rather than the usual user-specific install. It's a bit more complex, but provides a centralized RVM installation managed by root.

Comment: Greg's right, use this to set you up in development http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ and this in production: http://ryanbigg.com/deployment/getting_started_ubuntu.html